# Retrofit ignores some requests

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I have an android app with server communication layer, implemented with Retrofit 2. It sends requests with .enqueue method. All API methods works fine, except one. In this case after calling .enqueue nothing happents. And i mean it) No exceptions, no messages in logcat. Just silence. Maybe some1 faced with dimilar situation?

Comment: show us your code

Comment: I can't - NDA. But i can say, that its identical to Retrofit docs. And it works with all cases except one. It's good old GET request with two Query parametes.

Comment: Are you able to hit that service using postman and getting the valid response?

Comment: Yep, server responds normally